# Group a list of anonymous type objects using linq and lambda

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda, anonymous-types

```
 List<object> Students = new List<object>() {
    new { Name = "A", Age = 28, Height = 175 },
    new { Name = "B", Age = 29, Height = 176 },
    new { Name = "C", Age = 30, Height = 177 },
    new { Name = "D", Age = 31, Height = 178 },
    new { Name = "A", Age = 32, Height = 179 },
    new { Name = "E", Age = 33, Height = 180 },
    new { Name = "A", Age = 34, Height = 181 },
    new { Name = "F", Age = 35, Height = 182 },
    new { Name = "B", Age = 36, Height = 183 }
};
```

1) how can I group the above list by Age?

I tried something like `var test = Students.GroupBy(x=> x.Age);`, but it didn't work.

2) I want to create a dictionary which has Name as `Key` and Height as `Value` . How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to use straight object wont work because object does not have Age property. It is better for you to use predefined class with Name, Age and Height properties. It will be much more readable and type safe...

```
class Student
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
   public int Height {get; set;}

   public Student() {} //you would need parameterless constructor to use "new Student {...}"
   public Student(string name, int age, int height)
   {
      Name = name;
      Age = age;
      Height = height;
   }
}
var Students = new List<Student>() 
                   { 
                      new Student { Name = "A", Age = 29, Height = 175 },  //using initializer
                      new Student("B", 30, 176), //using constructor
                      ... 
                   };
```

But if it is impossible - you can always use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd264741.aspx). Like this:

```
List<dynamic> Students = new List<dynamic>() 
                             { 
                                new { Name = "A", Age = 28, Height = 175 }, 
                                ...
                             };
var test = Students.GroupBy(x=> x.Age);
```

and for dictionary - use `ToDictionary`:

```
var test = Students.ToDictionary(x=> x.Name, x => x.Height);
```

however you might want to try `ToLookup` because you have duplicates in your Names :)

Comment: in order to add Student objects to the list, we again use something like `new Student { Name = "A", Age = 28, Height = 175 }`?

Comment: Yes. Or if you want you can add constructor for that class.

Comment: ,an example for the constructor?

Comment: @burhan I meant the simplest constructor :) Updated example just in case

Comment: @burhan, no you cant. In order to achieve this you would need to create your own collection class - probably inheriting from `List<Student>` and adding your own `Add` method.

Comment: simply `new Student();` or `new Student { ...};` Isuggest you to start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx

Comment: in some codes, GroupBy method takes 2 parameters. what is the second parameter for?

Comment: @burhan: What in the documentation is unclear? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx as you can see there are several overloads with multiple parameters so even if you did have some confusion you'd want to narrow it down a bit...

Comment: @Chris, in this statement: `var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2, (id, xs) => xs.Max(x => x.value));`  What is `id` variable in `(id,xs)` for? because `id` hasnt been used in the `xs.Max(x => x.value)` expression. to me, `xs => xs.Max(x => x.value)` is sufficient. why two variables?

Comment: @burhan: Because the `GroupBy` overload in question here is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393(v=vs.110).aspx . The second argument is of type `Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult>`. This means it has two input parameters and the output. In this case id is the key and xs is the grouped elements. id isn't used but it has to be there or the compiler will complained that it can't find the right overload or it might confuse it with `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx` (I'm not quite sure which withotu trying).

Comment: that is, to use Max method, it needs a variable as grouped elements to work on(namely xs). because of this GroupBy with 2 input parameters is used here. i think, it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
 var Students = new []{
    new { Name = "A", Age = 28, Height = 175 },
    new { Name = "B", Age = 29, Height = 176 },
    new { Name = "C", Age = 30, Height = 177 },
    new { Name = "D", Age = 31, Height = 178 },
    new { Name = "A", Age = 32, Height = 179 },
    new { Name = "E", Age = 33, Height = 180 },
    new { Name = "A", Age = 34, Height = 181 },
    new { Name = "F", Age = 35, Height = 182 },
    new { Name = "B", Age = 36, Height = 183 }
}.ToList();

var groupedStudents = Students.GroupBy(x=>x.Age);
```

The key differences are that I create an anonymous list (I don't actually need the `.ToList()` but I'm showing you how in case you want to do any other List stuff with it). The advantage of this is that `ToList` is a generic method that can infer what the type is from the enumerable it is working on which in this case is an enumerable of anonymous types.

Of course many times you might be better off just creating a `Student` object rather than using an anonymous one.

As for creating a dictionary with name as key and height as value - you can't. Dictionaries need to have unique keys and you have multiple items with the same name here so trying to do `ToDictionary()` it wouldn't work.

You could try using `ToLookup()` which would take a key to an enumerable of matching values (similar to group by but easier to look things up).